# Bugzilla missing super user information

Tags: authentication, login, bugzilla

I set up Bugzilla server on my system and accidentally lost login for it. I have done a research on it but nothing has worked so far. Things that I tried to do are:

I tried adding more administrative users using the MySQL interface. Ran "mysql" from the command line, and use the following commands:

```
mysql> use bugs;<br />
mysql>  update profiles set groupset=0x7ffffffffffffff where login_name = "admin";<br />
```

I get an error message saying:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'groupset' in 'field list'
```

I also found my e-mail that I used for admin for registration but I cannot recover my password:

```
mysql> select login_name from profiles where userid=1; 
+-------------------+
| login_name        |
+-------------------+
| admin@example.com |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Anytime I tried to delete a super user I got this:

```
mysql> delete from  profiles where userid=1; 
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bugzilla`.`components`, CONSTRAINT `fk_components_initialowner_profiles_userid` FOREIGN KEY (`initialowner`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`userid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
mysql> update profiles set groupset=0x7ffffffffffffff where login_name = "(user's login name)";
```

I changed my password using

```
sudo checksetup.pl --reset-password=admin@example.com
```

Tried to log in to localhost Bugzilla
user id: admin@example.com
password: (my password)

I get the following internal error:

```
Bugzilla has suffered an internal error. Please save this page and send it to admin@example.com with details of what you were doing at the time this message appeared.

There was an error sending mail from 'bugzilla-daemon' to 'admin@example.com': Couldn't find 'sendmail' executable in your PATH and $Email::Send::Sendmail::SENDMAIL is not set
Traceback:

 at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 190
    Bugzilla::Mailer::MessageToMTA(...) called at Bugzilla/Token.pm line 307
    Bugzilla::Token::Cancel(...) called at Bugzilla/Token.pm line 323
    Bugzilla::Token::DeletePasswordTokens(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth/Verify/DB.pm line 85
    Bugzilla::Auth::Verify::DB::check_credentials(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth/Verify/Stack.pm line 62
    Bugzilla::Auth::Verify::Stack::check_credentials(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 72
    Bugzilla::Auth::login(...) called at Bugzilla.pm line 345
    Bugzilla::login(...) called at /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 40
```

Is there way to change username?

Nothing is working so far. How can I login into Bugzilla? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo checksetup.pl --reset-password=admin@example.com
```

is the correct solution to your problem of not being able to log in because you lost the password.

But then, you have hit a different problem. Your email config is not set up correctly. (Bugzilla shouldn't throw an error in this case; you might want to file a bug on that.)

To work around it temporarily, edit the file

```
data/params
```

and set 'mail_delivery_method' to 'Test'. That should prevent it looking for sendmail.

Gerv